# MYSQL Obtener el valor máximo de una columna

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos, phpmyadmin

Tengo una tabla de cursos donde necesito obtener su titulo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y tengo otra tabla donde están las notas de los cursos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como puedo obtener la nota máxima (exe_result) de cada examen por curso teniendo en cuenta que los usuarios pueden realizar mas de 1 intento por examen?

Comment: Haciendo un MAX(exe_result) y agrupando por curso y usuario

Comment: ¿Has intentando algo hasta ahora? ¿Dónde te encuentras bloqueado en base a ese intento?

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Agrega lo que intentaste en la pregunta (usa el boton [edit]). Creo que no me funciona no es una respuesta valida. aclara caul es el resultado esperado y cual el resultado que obtuviste.

Comment: @A.Cedano He llegado hasta esta consulta, pero aun así no me trae solo el valor máximo, puesto que me trae el resultado de los otros intentos: SELECT e.exe_user_id, c.title, e.c_id, e.result, e.exe_date
FROM course AS c
LEFT JOIN (
 SELECT c_id, exe_user_id, MAX(exe_result) AS result, exe_date
 FROM track_e_exercises
    GROUP BY c_id, exe_user_id, exe_date) AS e ON e.c_id = c.id

Comment: Intenta así más bien: **`SELECT e.exe_user_id, c.title, e.c_id, e.result, e.exe_date, MAX(e.exe_result) AS result FROM course AS c LEFT JOIN track_e_exercises AS e ON e.c_id = c.id GROUP BY e.c_id, e.exe_user_id;`** Por ejemplo, no entiendo por qué pones la fecha en el `GROUP BY` ¿Necesitas agrupar por fechas también?

Comment: @A.Cedano, esa consulta me retorna todos los intentos, no el intento con el resultado más alto :(

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo solucione, dejo la consulta que me funciono:

```
SELECT c.title, e.c_id, e.exe_user_id, e.result
                FROM course as c
                INNER JOIN (
                    SELECT c_id, exe_user_id, MAX(exe_result) AS result
                    FROM track_e_exercises
                    GROUP BY c_id, exe_user_id) AS e ON c.id = e.c_id
```